# Можно ли изменить цвет текста элемента в состоянии Enabled = false?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SearchButton становится неактивным по нажатию 1 из кнопок на форме. Серый цвет на зеленой панели не виден. Возможно ли изменить его на какой-либо другой, когда SearchButton находится в выключенном состоянии.

P.S. "if (!SearchButton.Enabled)" не работает

Answer (score 0):

сам текст не меняется можно поменять только backgroud

```
     private void button1_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Enabled)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Brown;
        }
    }
```